# shell function in bash file

Tags: linux, bash, function, shell

I have a few command that I would like to run faster. Best solution seems to be an alias (in fact, a function because I need to use avec few arguments). I would like my alias to be run when the system starts. So I've created a bash file to execute it. To create my function, I key this stuff in my shell :

```
function myFunction() { command 1 ; command 2 ; etc... }
```

But here is the problem ! My bash file do not execute the whole command because myFunction is reconized as... a function ! But an internal function.

So is there any way to make the file executing the whole function ? 
Thanks a lot guys !

Comment: You need to actually call the function (you have only defined it). Also try and `source` the script so the definition persists.

Comment: Is `function myFunction() {}` actually valid? I always define functions as just `myFunction() {}`

Comment: Yes it works when I tip it directly in the shell but not when I run the bash file. How can I "source" the code ?

Answer (score 1):

You could just define the function in your ~/.bashrc or from there, source the file in which it is defined.

Comment: The problem is, I'm not root on the machine

Comment: Well if you don't have access to the file, you can just create a new one and define the function inside, then `source` the file once so that the current shell remembers the function definition.